# How to convert date through hot_to_r function

Tags: r, shiny, rhandsontable

I am trying to convert rhandsontable object to an r object through hot_to_r , but i figured that my table have a date column , and due to that it throws me an error "no method or default for coercing “character” to “NA”. I tried dropping the date column and without it, it runs fine. Any idea what do i do to fix this ?

here is the sample code, that runs into the same problem

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(rhandsontable)

ui <- dashboardPage(skin = 'green',

      dashboardHeader( title = "TD Securities", titleWidth = 280),

      dashboardSidebar(width = 280  ),

      dashboardBody( 

      fluidRow(

      column(4,
      helpText("editable table"),
      rHandsontableOutput("table"),
      br(),
      actionButton("saveBtn","Save"))


      )))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  # creat a table with date column

  mtcars1<- transform(mtcars,date = Sys.Date())

  # returns rhandsontable type object - editable excel type grid data
  output$table <- renderRHandsontable({

    rhandsontable( mtcars1) # converts the R dataframe to rhandsontable object 
  })

  # on click of button the file will be saved to the working directory
  observeEvent(input$saveBtn, {

               write.csv(hot_to_r(), file = "MyData.csv",row.names = FALSE)})

  # hot_to_r() converts the rhandsontable object to r data object

})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: just added a sample example

Comment: Your sample code is working fine for me, I just had to add input$table as an argument for hot_to_r, like this: `write.csv(hot_to_r(input$table), file = "MyData.csv",row.names = FALSE)})`

Comment: In any case, you can try formatting the column to be sure it is being treated as date, using this logic:
`rhandsontable(data) %>%
  hot_col("Date", dateFormat = "DD/MM/YYYY", type = "date")`

Comment: Thank you, it works now

Comment: another issue, when i try to  use the logic above (hot_col) it gives me this "error,ttempt to select less than one element in get1index" , what does this mean ?